# Optimizing loop for checks in a large R dataframe

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe where each row logs a child's visit to a health establishment:

```
head(cred2015)
DNI_PN   COD_ESTAB   FEC_ATEN SEXO    FEC_NAC CONTROL
60099999      3697 2015-08-04    2 2015-07-28       2
60099999      3697 2015-08-14    2 2015-07-28       3
60099999      3697 2015-08-28    2 2015-07-28       1
60099999      3697 2015-09-28    2 2015-07-28       2
60099999      3697 2015-10-28    2 2015-07-28       3
60999999      3697 2015-11-28    2 2015-07-28       4
```

`DNI_PN` identifies individuals, `FEC_NAC` is their birthdate and `FEC_ATEN` the visit date.

There is a given visit schedule children must follow and I wish to check, for each one of those visits, if the child attended or not. This is what my current attempt looks like:

```
#Create a vector with unique identifiers to loop over
dni<-unique(cred2015$DNI_PN)

#The first scheduled visit must happen 7 days after birth.
#My custom function takes a lower and upper date limit for wiggle room.
conRN1<-sapply(dni,checkCRED,5,9)

#The function in question:
checkCRED<-function(idnum,llim,ulim){
  require('magrittr')

  #Examine visits from one individual at a time
  subcred<-cred2015 %>% subset(DNI_PN == idnum)

  #Check if the lower limit would fall inside the year 2015
  if(as.Date("2015-12-31","%Y-%m-%d")-unique(subcred$FEC_NAC)>llim){

  #Note if a visit happened within the time window
    if((subcred %>% subset(FEC_ATEN-FEC_NAC>=llim & FEC_ATEN-FEC_NAC<=ulim))$CONTROL %>% length > 0){
      1 #On time
    } else {
      0 #Wasn't on time
    }
  }else{
    NA #Exclude if CRED date not in database range
  }
}
```

Currently, doing this for 1000 different individuals takes almost a minute which is unacceptable given I need to evaluate over 12 different scheduled visits for hundreds of thousands of individuals.

Note that the `CONTROL` variable keeps track of what visit the observation corresponds to but it resets according to a sub-schedule (up to 2 visits in the first month, up to 11 in the first year, up to 6 in the second year, etc) so I couldn't find any use for it but I left it in case somewhat smarter than me figures a solution involving it.

The answer need not be restricted to base R.

Data

```
structure(list(DNI_PN = c(60099999, 60099999, 60099999, 60099999, 
60099999, 60999999), COD_ESTAB = c(3697, 3697, 3697, 3697, 3697, 
3697), FEC_ATEN = structure(c(16651, 16661, 16675, 16706, 16736, 
16767), class = "Date"), SEXO = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), FEC_NAC = structure(c(16644, 
16644, 16644, 16644, 16644, 16644), class = "Date"), CONTROL = c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("DNI_PN", "COD_ESTAB", "FEC_ATEN", 
"SEXO", "FEC_NAC", "CONTROL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: `x <- cred2015$FEC_ATEN - cred2015$FEC_NAC; tapply(x >= 5 & x <= 7, cred2015$DNI_PN, any)` is what you want?

Comment: It is. I am really sorry you had to see the mess I whipped up. Thanks a lot.